# Upload a DLL to the Bin folder using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll

Is there any way to upload a DLL to the Bin directory of an ASP.NET website using the same website?

Comment: Use ftp to upload it or use remote site connection and paste dll file. there is no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Add it in you bin directory and set the 'Copy local' value to 'True', OR add it as a reference and do the same steps.

Greetings